# Word Puzzle - How to fix it going out of path?

Tags: java, arrays, file, if-statement, io

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction with this issue.

For my project in school, we need to make a "Word Puzzle" solver. So there is a .txt file with a "grid" of letters, along with actual words under this grid that the puzzle needs to look for and see if they exist in the puzzle.

```
example:
4 4
s e l f
w t r g
a o o v
g x q e
frog
swag
self
```

The 4 4 represents the puzzle will be 4 letters wide, and 4 letters high.

The problem I am running into is that if, for example, we are searching for "frog". My program finds the 'f', then moves on to the next character in the word 'r'. It finds the 'r', then moves onto the 'o'. This is where my problem is. The way my program is designed uses a bunch of if else statements to check if the letter above, below, left, right, upright, downright, upleft, or downleft of the current location contains the next letter we are looking for.

So what happens is that it will pick the wrong 'o', and then try to find the 'g' after moving to 'o's location, but it can't because it took the wrong path.

My question is this: does anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue? I don't want a direct coding answer if possible, since this is an academic assignment and I don't want to cheat, but if someone could lead me in the right direction, I would be ecstatic!

Thank you.

EDIT : Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/SJ4EePk7

Comment: Code sharing will save you time to describe your problem and to get quick attention.

Comment: This really depends on your "path" algorithm. Don't you want to check in all directions from the initial character for a certain distance if that "substring" is contained within some master list of words?

Comment: *"does anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue?"* It looks like your code is checking each nearby field for the searched letter and stops looking if it found one, maybe with a `break`. In that case, you can't/shouldn't break that search, so the `break` statement should be removed. That might be the only necessary thing to fix, but it is hard to say without the code.

Comment: I posted the code here: http://pastebin.com/SJ4EePk7 Please take a look and let me know what you think

Comment: Your code belongs into the question, not to another page with a link in the comments ;P.

Comment: Please. Please help.

Comment: I am assuming you want to search string even in substring of puzzle. i.e. in `self`, `elf` is also a word.

Comment: It is only searching for the words given under the puzzle, so "elf" is irrelevant.

Comment: I did mean if `elf` is in list, is your code supposed to match it too, which is a subpart of string.

Comment: Is there any special algorithm that should be implemented?

Comment: KMPL to just search text in another text which makes searching faster @Pooya

Answer (score 0):

their are 4 orientations in any your word could be found.

1. Horizontal (4 rows)
2. Vertical (4 rows)
3. Diagonal 1 - topleft to bottomright (7 rows)
4. Diagonal 2 - topright to bottomleft (7 rows)

Create program to get strings from all these orientations

```
s e l f  
w t r g  
a o o v  
g x q e
```

1. Horizontal : 
   [`self`, `wtrg`, `aoov`, `gxqe`]
2. Vertical :
   [`swag`, `etox`, `lroq`, `fgve`]
3. Diagonal 1 : 
   [`s`, `ew`, `lta`, `frog`, `gox`, `vq`, `e`]
4. Diagonal 2 : 
   [`f`, `lg`, `erv`, `stoe`, `woq`, `ax`, `g`]

Now to check if your strings are found in these strings you can use `String.contains(...)` function.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee when the word starts from bottom to top such as `xote` (if it was a real word).

Comment: then you will have to take two more orientation (1 extra for horizontal, and 1 for vertical)